# Why did running this script as administrator cause it to create a 1GB folder?

Tags: windows, batch

A batch script designed to copy another batch script to users' Documents folders in Windows had the undesired effect of creating a ~1GB folder in one user's Documents folder when he ran it with administrator privileges. Having reviewed the script, I'm still not sure what caused this behaviour.

This is the source, called test1_install:

```
@echo off
mkdir %userprofile%\Documents\test1
copy *.* "%userprofile%\Documents\test1\" /Y
copy "test1 - Shortcut.lnk" "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /Y
```

This is placed in a folder that contains three other files - 'test1.bat', 'input.txt' and 'test1 - Shortcut.lnk'. The entire folder is just 16KB in size.

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious. What is it?

Comment: What files ended up in the destination folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `copy *.* "%userprofile%\Documents\test1\" /Y` makes the batch copy data not from the directory it **is stored in**, but from the directory **it is called from**. Insert `cd /d %~dp0%` after the first line, to make the latter directory be the former.